# Hide errors in console chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Currently user of google Chrome, I wish when I'm in my console, that my javascript errors are not displayed.
I have long this feature on the forums, without success!

Answer (score 7):

In the Console click the *"Default levels"* drop down, then select *"Errors"* to un-check it. This will hide error messages from the console.

[image]

Comment: thank you. and for the total located to the right of console ?

Comment: @MikeTilam From what I know I don't think there is a setting to hide that, although it's not really in the way.

Answer (score 2):

- Open **Console Settings**
- Then check **User messages only** option.

It should works.

Comment: thank you. and for the total located to the right of console ?